# Is base 64 part of cryptography?

Tags: cryptography

Is Base 64 part of cryptography. Does Base 64 provides any security? Does Base 64 encrypt and decrypt data??

Comment: Some more information about what you want to achive could help us be more helpful.

Answer (score 5):

[No.](http://google.com/?q=base%2064)

Well, to be really very pedantic, if you are trying to hide content from a complete-computer novice who doesn't really want the content very much: sure, it's plenty good. It's a bit better than the [Caesar Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

Comment: The only reason everyone thinks base64 is a crypto algo is because (a). It obfuscates text and (b). The most often referenced base64 routine lives in the libssl library with key management algos and that is usually included along with the libcrypto library which contains actual crypto algos.

Comment: @Marc, I figured the misconception stemmed from using the terms `encode` and `decode`. Most people don't distinguish between `encode` and `encrypt`.

Comment: You're probably right. I thought it was a crypto algo myself when I started using github and had to generate keys for my account. I was fooled by the fact that I had to copy and paste a base64 output after generating the public key. Months later, I answered a question in stackoverflow and found out base64 is just an encoder!

Answer (score 4):

No. Base64 is an encoding. It only translate characters to another format.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64):

> Base64 is a group of similar encoding
>   schemes that represent binary data in
>   an ASCII string format by translating
>   it into a radix-64 representation.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is simply a method of encoding data, nothing else. I suggest you read this wikipedia article on [Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.

Base 64 is an encoding scheme.

Encoding binary files in base64 was/is a way to send files over email by encoding the binary as textual information.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64):

> Base64 encoding schemes are commonly used when there is a need to encode binary data that needs be stored and transferred over media that are designed to deal with textual data.